# How to fix a loose zoom ring on a Canon 17-40mm?

Tags: lens, canon, repair

I'm trying to fix a Canon 17-40mm with loose screws under the zoom ring.

I saw that there is a simple way to replace the screws on the zoom ring of the 17-40mm Canon zoom lens. I slipped off the cover and have one of the loose screws. The other is still in the lens.

Does anyone have images of where they go and how to achieve this?

Comment: http://notabs.org/canon/ef17-40/disassembly.html

Comment: http://www.strappe.com/pics/manuals/photography/EF17-40%204.0L%20USM.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have images of where they go and how to achieve this?

Yes, there is a [nice visual guide here](http://notabs.org/canon/ef17-40/disassembly.html) explaining how to disassemble the lens. Follow it to fix yours back into shape.

Comment: You might want to add a short summary of the steps, given that the link might go stale/die. As-is, this is a link-only answer.